# How can I modify a 2d array passed to a function?

Tags: c, arrays, function, 2d

Why does the following code give me a segmentation fault?

```
#define MAXROWS 10
#define MAXCOLS 10
void getInput (int *data[MAXROWS][MAXCOLS]) {
  int rows, cols;
  int curRow, curCol;
  printf ("How many rows and cols?");
  scanf ("%d %d", rows, cols);

  for (curRow = 0; curRow < rows; curRow++) {
    for (curCol = 0; curCol < cols; curCol++) {
      scanf ("%d", data[curRow][curCol]);
      printf ("%d\n", *data[curRow][curCol]);
    }
  }
}

void main () {
  int data[MAXROWS][MAXCOLS];

  getInput (data);
}
```

It seems to be that the `scanf` and `printf` statements aren't getting the right data type passed in, but I can't work out what they *should* be.

How can I change it so that it works properly?

Comment: At what point are you getting the seg fault?

Comment: When it starts to read the values into *data*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This declares an array of `MAXROWS` arrays of pointers to `int`.

```
int *data[MAXROWS][MAXCOLS];
```

However, in a function definition, top level arrays (of any size) are equivalent to pointers because arrays always decay to pointers to the type of the array member on passing to a function.

So your function definition is equivalent to:

```
void getInput (int *(*data)[MAXCOLS])
```

i.e. a pointer to an array of `MAXCOLS` pointers to `int`.

As your code stands, you never initialize any of the `int` pointers in the array, as you are passing a 2d array of `int`s as a pointer to a 2d array of `int *`.

What you probably want to pass, is a pointer to an array of `MAXCOLS`  `int`:

```
void getInput (int (*data)[MAXCOLS])
```

or equivalently:

```
void getInput (int data[][MAXCOLS])
```

Then you do the following:

```
int main(void)
{
    int data[MAXROWS][MAXCOLS];

    getInput(data);

    return 0;
}
```

You are then passing your 2d array as a pointer to its first element (a pointer to a row or an array of `MAXCOLS` `int`s).

If you make sure change be sure to change:

```
  scanf ("%d", data[curRow][curCol]);
  printf ("%d\n", *data[curRow][curCol]);
```

to:

```
  scanf ("%d", &data[curRow][curCol]);
  printf ("%d\n", data[curRow][curCol]);
```

Also, check your parameters here:

```
scanf ("%d %d", &rows, &cols);
```

You need to be passing pointers to `rows` and `cols`.

Make sure to add some bounds checking to your input function so that you don't attempt to read more rows and columns than `MAXROWS` or `MAXCOLS`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation and the sample code as well!

Answer (score 0):

scanf accepts address of variables, not the content of it:

```
void getInput (int data[][MAXCOLS]) {
  int rows, cols;
  int curRow, curCol;
  printf ("How many rows and cols?");
  scanf ("%d %d", &rows, &cols);
  //scanf ("%d %d", &rows, &cols);
  for (curRow = 0; curRow < rows; curRow++) {
    for (curCol = 0; curCol < cols; curCol++) {
          scanf ("%d", &data[curRow][curCol]);
          printf ("%d\n", data[curRow][curCol]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I ran it and it works for me. What is the error now?
There were 4 fixed in the function above, have you done them all?

Answer (score 0):

There were a few different problems.

First, when passing arrays to functions you only need the definition of N-1 dimensions.  For example if you're passing a 3D array you would put the size of the last 2 dimensions in the function sig and leave the first one empty.

```
foo(int threeD[][10][15]);
```

Second, scanf takes the address of the argument, which for your array looks like this

```
&data[curRow][curCol]
```

Third, you should always check the range of you input to make sure it's valid:

```
  if (rows > MAXROWS || cols > MAXCOLS) {
    printf("Bad array dimensions\n");
    return;
  }
```

Fourth, always compile with all warnings turned on - the compiler will warn you about allot of these things:

```
gcc -Wall pass_array.c -o pass_array
```

.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXROWS 10
#define MAXCOLS 10

void getInput (int data[][MAXCOLS]) {
  int rows, cols;
  int curRow, curCol;
  printf ("How many rows and cols?");
  scanf ("%d %d", &rows, &cols);

  if (rows > MAXROWS || cols > MAXCOLS) {
    printf("Bad array dimensions\n");
    return;
  }

  for (curRow = 0; curRow < rows; curRow++) {
    for (curCol = 0; curCol < cols; curCol++) {
      scanf ("%d", &data[curRow][curCol]);
      printf ("%d\n", data[curRow][curCol]);
    }
  }
}

int main () {
  int data[MAXROWS][MAXCOLS];

  getInput (data);
    return 0;
}
```